# Simplify and compute the MGF of $[1-(1-(1-e^{-ax})^{N_1})(1-(1-e^{-ax})^{N_2})]^{M-1} $

Tags: binomial-theorem, moment-generating-functions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ two random variable with CDF 
\begin{align}
F_{X_1}(x)&=(1-e^{-ax})^{N_1}\\
F_{X_2}(x)&=(1-e^{-ax})^{N^2}
\end{align}
 Let $Z$ random variable with CDF 
$$
F_Z(z)=[1-(1-F_{X_1}(x))(1-F_{X_2}(x))]^M
$$
The PDF is the derivation of CDF given by 
$$
f_Z(x)=M[1-(1-F_{X_1}(x))(1-F_{X_2}(x))]^{M-1}(f_{X1}(x)+f_{X2}(x)-f_{X1}(x)F_{X2}(x)-f_{X2}(x)F_{X1}(x)
$$
My Problem is to compute the Moment generatrice function of $Z$.

I would like to write $f_Z(x)$ in term of sum exponential, because it easy to compute the MGF.

The difficult part in $f_Z(x)$ is 
$$
A=[1-(1-F_{X_1}(x))(1-F_{X_2}(x))]^{M-1}
$$
After i use binomial theorem i arrive to the flowing result

$$A=\sum_{z=0}^{M-1}\binom{M-1}{z}(-1)^z
\begin{pmatrix}
1-\sum_{m=0}^{N_1}\binom{N_1}{m}(-1)^me^{-xm}
\end{pmatrix}^z\begin{pmatrix}
1-\sum_{m=0}^{N_2}\binom{N_2}{m}(-1)^me^{-xm}
\end{pmatrix}^z$$

I found in paper the following simplification 
$$
A=\sum_{z=0}^{N-1}\sum_{a=0}^{z}\sum_{b=0}^{z}\sum_{n=0}^{aN_1}\sum_{m=0}^{bN_2}\binom{N-1}{z}\binom{z}{a}\binom{z}{b}\binom{aN_1}{n}\binom{aN_2}{m}(-1)^{z+a+b+n+m}
me^{-x(m+n)}
$$
Can any one explain to me how the simplify it.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{s=0}^S {S\choose s}(-1)^sX^s=(1-X)^S$

Comment: I was in this case know i would like to write in form sum of Exponential function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You are asking "does this sum simplify", it does, to $(1-e^{-x})^{M(N-1)}$. Now you are saying you want to write it as a sum of exponentials... so you don't want it simplified? What exactly are you asking then? If you are interested in behavior for small $x$, Taylor expand $e^{-x}$ and then expand the power (to whatever order of $x$ you're interested in), instead of the other way around.

Comment: Sorry didn't make it clear, in fact i want to compute the moment generatrice function MGF of the above expression. Since or if we can write as something like the flowing form  $$\sum_{}^{}\sum_{}{}\binom{}{}\binom{}{} e^{x}$$, it will be easy to compute the MGF. However your idée about Taylor series is perfect because a lot paper use Taylor series  can you give me  the solution thanks

Comment: I have solution but i didn't understand how they do it. I will add may be  you can explain to me

Comment: Yeah, I suggest you write the full question, together with the full solution and then explain which part of the solution does not make sense to you. Then I or someone else can resolve your confusion effectively.

Comment: I have put all the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use the notation $\mu=M-1$. Define $X=e^{-ax}$ and  $F_i=(1-X)^{N_i}$. Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left[1-(1-F_1)(1-F_2)\right]^\mu \\
\xrightarrow{\text{expand }(\cdots)^\mu} &\sum_{z=0}^\mu \binom{\mu}{z}(-1)^z (1-F_1)^z(1-F_2)^{z}
\\
\xrightarrow{\text{expand }(1-F_i)^z}&
\sum_{z=0}^\mu \binom{\mu}{z}(-1)^z \sum_{a=0}^z \binom{z}{a}(-1)^a F_1^a
\sum_{b=0}^z \binom{z}{b}(-1)^b F_2^b\\
\xrightarrow{F_i=(1-X)^{N_i}}&
\sum_{z=0}^\mu
\sum_{a=0}^z
\sum_{b=0}^z \binom{\mu}{z}\binom{z}{a}\binom{z}{b}(-1)^{z+a+b} (1-X)^{aN_1}
(1-X)^{bN_2}\\
\xrightarrow{\text{expand }(1-X)^{\cdots}}&
\sum_{z=0}^\mu
\sum_{a=0}^z
\sum_{b=0}^z
\binom{\mu}{z}\binom{z}{a}\binom{z}{b}(-1)^{z+a+b}
\sum_{m=0}^{aN_1}\binom{aN_1}{m}(-1)^m X^m
\sum_{n=0}^{bN_2}
\binom{bN_2}{n}(-1)^n X^n
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: It look for me  is very good, However i have used matlab to check the values without and with binomial expansion. The result are very  close for small value of  $M, N_1$ and $N_2$. However more $x$ be small and   $M, N_1$ and $N_2$ increase the two become different value is normal, I mean we should have same value for all value of $x$ $M$ $N_1$ and $N_2$. Finally I would like to thank you so much # Hamed for given me your time and helping me and thank you again.

Comment: It is not unusual for Matlab to give different values for the same function but in different forms at certain ranges. A different expression means Matlab uses a different method for numerical calculation. Different methods mean different errors. Also for small values, these differences might become significant due to a small number (bitwise) being essentially the same as a very big number. All numerical calculation methods eventually break somewhere.

Comment: Ok #hamid Thank you so much. Your anser it was perfect for me. have nice Day and good luck in you PhD. I am also Phd Student In wireless communication.